# Unable to find name celery

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to setup celery and getting the following error.

```
    (ENV) E:\src\credixo\test>python celeryexperiments\driver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "celeryexperiments\driver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from alltasks.widget1 import download
  File "E:\src\credixo\test\celeryexperiments\alltasks\widget1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from celery import task
  File "E:\src\credixo\test\celeryexperiments\celery.py", line 1, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'
```

Following is my directory structure.

```
celeryexperiments
   +__init__.py
   +celery.py
   +driver.py
   +alltasks
       +__init__.py
       +widget1.py
```

Following are the contents.
1. driver.py

```
from alltasks.widget1 import download
download.delay('google.com')
```

2. celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celeryexperiments')
app.conf.update(
    BROKER_URL='redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=False,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['application/json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_TIMEZONE='Asia/Kolkata'
)
app.autodiscover_tasks(['celeryexperiments.alltasks.widget1'])
```

3. widget1.py
from celery import task

```
@task(name="download", ignore_result=False, bind=True)
def download(self, url):
    print('{0} is downloaded'.format(url))
```

The celery worker starts properly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your file is named `celery.py`. This hides the `celery` library. Rename your module and this error should go away (assuming you have celery installed).

Comment: I have tried it. But if I rename celery the workers do not start.                  
 AttributeError: module 'celeryexperiments' has no attribute 'celery'